# weird rotate/move problem with curves / is there a easy way to recreate curves?

Tags: bezier-curves, transforms

I was trying to make hair with curves, but then i got some weird problem with some of them that when i move or rotate they would randomly tremble and get in a different position in relation to the others.

[image: some curves in a different position after rotating]

I would like to know what im doing that is causing it, or at least some easy and fast way to recriate the curves that doesn't cause this glitch.

Comment: That shouldn,t normally happen unless each hair strand is a separate object

Comment: i'm using separete curves to make the hair,

Comment: Did U tried to parent all the strands to an axis for example and rotate after? Cause it looks that at least some of them acts normally.

Comment: seems to fix the problem if i need to rotate all of them at the same time, which is quite nice, but i still have problems to rotate the ones that are broken.. thx anyway